# Unable to change interpreter to python 2.7.1 in PyCharm Community - Windows 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, pythoninterpreter

all instructions says in pycharm go to file->settings->python interpreter->show all->add interpreter tec.
So , when i change to location with python27 i get such error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caY4s.png)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.13.0.pyz\__main__.py", line 167, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.13.0.pyz\__main__.py", line 163, in run
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.13.0.pyz\virtualenv\__main__.py", line 18, in run
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.13.0.pyz\virtualenv\run\__init__.py", line 30, in cli_run
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.13.0.pyz\virtualenv\run\__init__.py", line 48, in session_via_cli
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.13.0.pyz\virtualenv\run\__init__.py", line 69, in build_parser
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.13.0.pyz\virtualenv\run\plugin\discovery.py", line 22, in get_discover
StopIteration
```

pls help. I can provide more info if needed.

I try to install python 2.7 and set enviromental variables in path i paste location of python27

currently my python version cheking in cmd is Python 2.7.1

Comment: Python 2.7 has been EOL for years now. Even Python 3 below 3.8 has been EOL for over a year: why are you trying to use 2.7 at all? Remove it, and install the current Python 3, then use that.

Answer (score 0):

From your error message it looks like that the *python-ce* plugin of PyCharm 2022.3.3 doesn't work with Python 2.7 anymore. Earlier versions of PyCharm may still work, try something near the beginning of 2020. Or try the newest PyCharm. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/python.html states that the newest PyCharm (still) supports Python 2.7, so the PyCharm developers may be interested in your bug report.

Alternatively, going forward, please consider using Python 3.x instead of Python 2.x. As written by **@Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans** in a comment: Python 2.7 has been EOL (end-of-life, unsupported) for years now. Even Python 3 below 3.8 has been EOL for over a year.